# Getting Error while trying to combine indicators

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Whenever I try adding my indicator to my chart I get this message from tradingview - Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 8: The arguments 'maxval', 'minval', and 'step' cannot be used with the input() function. You can use the input.int() or input.float() functions to specify a range of input data values. The code on line 8 is Multiplier = input(title="Trend Sensitivity", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3.0) can anyone please help with what im doing wrong

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the error message pretty clear?

You cannot use the `maxval`, `minval`, and `step` arguments with the `input()` function.

You should use `input.float()` instead.

```
Multiplier = input.float(title="Trend Sensitivity", step=0.1, defval=3.0)
```